# КАК ДОБАВИТЬ КНОПКИ В 3Д ИГРУ SWIFT

Tags: swift

я пытался сделать 3д игру гонки но я не знаю как сделать кнопки в SCNView и возможно ли это. Я пробывал добавить 2-й View с управлением однако как только я нажимаю на кнопку цикл renderer прекращал обновляться помогите пожалуйста

Comment: не могли бы вы пожалуйста помочь нам дать ответ на ваш вопрос включив в него больше подробностей?) например добавьте код который у вас вызывает затруднения, ибо пока только имея перед глазами ваш вопрос и ничего более довольно сложно дать адекватный ответ :(

Comment: простите я щас понял почему и у меня другой вопрос

Comment: мне нужно добавить 2 метода а именно чтобы первый вызывался когда кнопка нажата а второй когда ты отпускаешь кнопку

Comment: если вы знаете как это сделать помогите пожалуйста